# How to keep quotes in os.Args

Tags: string, go, quotes

I'm trying to print the command line arguments that I'm passing to my program, but the quotes (") are disappearing.

e.g:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.join(os.Args[1:], " "))
}
```

Then run using `go run test.go "status"` - This should print `"status"`, but it's printing `status`.

Answer (score 3):

This strictly depends on the shell executing the program and not Go itself. If you are using bash for example, try executing the program while escaping the double quotes. Like so

```
go run test.go '"status"'
# OR
go run test.go \"status\"
```

Comment: oh, really?? Isn't there anything that I can do to handle it in a better way?

Comment: As I said, this is strictly dependent on the shell you are using.

Comment: You can add the quotes inside your program.

Comment: In bash, your program cannot tell the difference between `go run test.go status` and `go run test.go "status"`. The quotes are removed by the shell before your program can see them.